# Could somebody explain or give an example what features does Facebook new SDK support for iOS 6?

Tags: ios6, single-sign-on, facebook-ios-sdk

On Facebook developer blog, it said "Updating the Facebook SDK with support for iOS 6.0".

But when I setup login following by https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login-with-facebook-using-ios-sdk/, I still need to input account/password again, even though I have login Facebook via settings on iOS6.

I am a new developer, so I am confused with "support for iOS 6.0"

Could somebody explain or give an example what features does Facebook new SDK support for iOS 6?